# How to log raw xml stanzas received in ejabberd?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

In the following code what code should go in to the **on_filter_packet** to log the received raw stanza's

```
init([Host]) ->
        ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 50),
        {ok, #state{}}.

on_filter_packet({From, To, Packet} = Input) ->
    % HOW TO LOG RAW XML PACKET ?
        Packet.
```

**EDIT:**

The code ** ?INFO_MSG("Running filter.  Debug: ~p ", [xml:element_to_string(Packet)]),** logs the following message to the file ** /var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log**

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2015-10-11 02:02:18 ===
I(<0.9757.0>:my_module:46) : Running filter.  Debug: [60,"iq",
                                                      [[32,"type",61,39,
                                                        "error",39],
                                                       [32,"id",61,39,
                                                        "purpled0f53aba",39]],
                                                      62,
                                                      [[60,"ping",
                                                        [[32,"xmlns",61,39,
                                                          "urn:xmpp:ping",39]],
                                                        47,62],
                                                       [60,"error",
                                                        [[32,"code",61,39,
                                                          "503",39],
                                                         [32,"type",61,39,
                                                          "cancel",39]],
                                                        62,
                                                        [[60,
                                                          "service-unavailable",
                                                          [[32,"xmlns",61,39,
                                                            "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas",
                                                            39]],
                                                          47,62]],
                                                        60,47,"error",62]],
                                                      60,47,"iq",62]
```

How to log the received Packet in **raw xml format**?

Comment: What do you mean by log? You could log anything through a variety of mechanisms, for example error_logger:info_msg("Packet hit filter: ~w", Packet]).

Comment: @Michael Added more description on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INFO_MSG macro and flatten your list:

```
on_filter_packet({From, To, Packet} = Input) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("My packet: ~p ", [lists:flatten(Packet)]),
    Packet.
```

Comment: It shows as erlang list. i am looking for something similar to the output of **exmpp_xml:document_to_binary/1**